# How to prove that A is normal if and only if there's a unitary matrix V,s.t. A*=AV?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix#cite_note-1, but I don't know how to prove it:

$A$ is normal if and only if there's a unitary matrix V,s.t. $A^*=AV$

Comment: Have you looked at Horn, pp. 109?

Comment: I can not find the book via internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A^* = AV$, then show that $A = A^* V^* = V^* A^*$. Likewise you can show that $V$ commutes with $A$. Using this you will easily show that $A^* A = A A^*$, i.e., that $A$ is normal.

Conversely, if $A$ is normal, then $A = U \Lambda U^*$, where $U$ is unitary, and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $A$. Recognise that we can write $\Lambda = R \Phi$, where $R$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are the magnitudes of the corresponding entries of $\Lambda$, and $\Phi$ is the diagonal matrix whose entries are complex numbers reflecting the phase of the corresponding entry in $\Lambda$. In other words if the $j^{\text{th}}$ diagonal entry of $\Lambda$ is $\lambda_j = r_j e^{i \phi_j}$, then $e^{i \phi_j}$ is the corresponding entry in $\Phi$.

Then $\Lambda^* = \Lambda \Phi^*  \Phi^*$, and
$$
A^* = U \Lambda^* U^* = (U \Lambda U^*)(U \Phi^* \Phi^* U^*) = AV,
$$
and we observe that $V$ is unitary, since $\Phi^*$ is.

This kind of idea is reflected in the [polar decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of a matrix.

Comment: I wonder how to show that $A^*V^*=V^*A^*$?

Comment: Perhaps you should first wonder how you would show that $A = V^* A^*$.

Comment: actually,as $A^*=AV$,then $A=V^*A^*$,so $A^*A=AVV^*A^*=AA^*$. Isn't  this more concise than yours? And we no need to show the commutation.

Comment: Yes, that's good.

Comment: But I can not understand why $\Lambda^* = \Lambda \Phi^* \Phi^*$?

Comment: For that, focus on a single entry $\lambda_j$. In other words, try to convince yourself of the truth of that statement in the case that $\Lambda = R\Phi$ is just a complex number with $R\Phi$ being its polar form. Then think about why it is also true for the diagonal matrices.

Comment: Here is my comprehesion:Since $\Lambda=R\Phi$,$R=R^*=\Lambda \Phi^*$,so $\Lambda^*=\Phi^*R^*=R^*\Phi^*=(\Lambda \Phi^*)\Phi^*$.

Comment: Good. Also, you will need to convince yourself that $\Phi$ is unitary. With that observation, and the observation that $\Lambda^* = R\Phi^*$, you can also obtain the result.