# Show that $ A^* = AU$ for a normal matrix A and a unitary matrix $U$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a normal matrix, how can I show that $A^*$ can be written on the form $A^* = AU$ where $U$ is a unitary matrix? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208627/how-to-prove-that-a-is-normal-if-and-only-if-theres-a-unitary-matrix-v-s-t-a?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following (maybe it's not the most optimal, but it answers the question). First, using a unitary transform $V$, you can diagonalize $A$ and $A^*$ (because you can do it with their self adjoint component, who commute since A is normal). Then compare the eigenvalues : they are conjugate, so $VA^*V^*=VAV^*U$ for a diagonal unitary $U$. Finally, cancel the $V$ on left and multiply on the right by $V$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $D=VAV^*$.

Comment: I understand that $D=VAV^*$ and $D^* = VA^*V^*$ and that the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^*$ are conjugate. And that $VA^*V^*=VAV^*U$ leads to $A^* = AV^*UV$ with $V^*UV$ being unitary. But the step $VA^*V^*=VAV^*U$ I don´t understand I am afraid. It means that D can be conjugated by multiplying with a unitary matrix from the right if i understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, because you can pass from a complex number $z$ to $\overline{z}$ by multiplying by an element of norm 1; in case they are 0, it's obvious, and otherwise, use that $z/\overline{z}$ has norm 1.