# How do I show that an operator $L$ is normal if and only if $L^*=LU$ for some unitary operator $U$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here $L$ is an operator on a finite dimensional complex space.

This question is in the exercises of a book I'm solving, and seems to be a follow up to the question asking to prove that an operator is normal iff its adjoint is its polynomial. I proved that, but trying t mimic that proof for this case is not working at all. I don't understand how to do this. I tried using the spectral theorem, but it doesn't seem to work straightaway.

Comment: Which book is it?

Comment: Peter Peterson's linear algebra

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208627/how-to-prove-that-a-is-normal-if-and-only-if-theres-a-unitary-matrix-v-s-t-a.